# How can we use dateadd function inside a date() function

Tags: sql, ibatis

I want to get values between two dates.Here the Created on is '2016-02-08 10:55:23' i.e with date and time.This query works well.

```
select  E.Id as StaffId,
        SUM(IC.AmountReceived) as totalAmount,INV.InvoiceType as AccountType
from invoice_collection IC,employee E ,invoice INV
where IC.CollectedBy=E.id and IC.OperatorCode=#operatorCode#
        and INV.InvoiceNo=IC.InvoiceNo and E.Id=#staffId#
        and TxnDate > #CreatedOn#
group by INV.InvoiceType;
```

Issue
When i'm modifying  my code as show below ,it does not show up any values.

```
select  E.Id as StaffId,
        SUM(IC.AmountReceived) as totalAmount,INV.InvoiceType as AccountType
from invoice_collection IC,employee E ,invoice INV
where IC.CollectedBy=E.id and IC.OperatorCode=#operatorCode#
            and INV.InvoiceNo=IC.InvoiceNo and E.Id=#staffId#
            and TxnDate > #CreatedOn# and TxnDate < date(dateadd(day,1,#CreatedOn#))
group by INV.InvoiceType;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
TxnDate > #CreatedOn# AND TxnDate < DATEADD(d,DATEDIFF(day,0,dateadd(day,1,#CreatedOn#)),0)
```

Comment: <= makes wrong fetch. i just need only from (eg-'2016-08-02 12:10:23' to 2016-09-02 00:00:00) .Please help me

Comment: what is the value of CreatedOn date

Comment: It is set as 2016-07-02 12:10:23 in the bean class.if i'm coding with <= the sum() returns yesterdays and today values from table.I'm trying to get values from yesterday only.

Comment: i just used dateadd, but it just added the day like(2016-08-02 12:10:23)i.e today till 12:10:23,the matter is i just need only upto 2016-07-02 00:00:00,is there any way to solve in sql

Comment: from greater than 2016-07-02 12:10:23 to less than 2016-08-02 00:00:00